# Product features / components / attributes data set

Tags: metadata

I am desperately looking for a way to either create or find an existing data set for products that lists the most common features / components or attributes of that product.

An example could be:

**DSLR camera**

- Camera
- Megapixels
- Lens
- Digital
- Glass
- Pro
- Shutter
- LCD
- Optical
- Zoom
- Resolution
- Megapixels
- CCD
- CMOS
- Stabilisation
- Macro
- Telephoto
- Wide angle
- Filters
- Batteries
- Flash
- Lighting
- Memory card

As can be seen this example, I just listed as many attributes I could, related to a specific product. Such that you might do in a brainstorming session on a product.

I need a way in order to do this at scale. I am looking for all help possible on this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

A quick search led me to [this set of product details from Amazon in 2014](https://github.com/SamTube405/Amazon-E-commerce-Data-set).

The description mentions:

> The dataset covers products from 6 main categories, Automotive, Books, Electronics, Movies, Phones and Home including 1529 sub-categories. All products are listed over 334 independent attributes & the size 2000K of value space.

Some of the attributes might be a little useless for a machine learning model, but other may help you do things quite nicely, like clustering.

Here is an actual example from the dataset for a DSLR camera:

```
ITEM 1604
Binding=Electronics
Brand=Case Logic
Color=Black
EAN=0085854223799
EANList=0085854223799
Feature=Compatible with DSLR camera with attached lens
Feature=Fitted Day Holster provides bump and scratch protection
Feature=Holster tether attaches to the camera's strap so you never set the case down to take a shot
Feature=Internal dedicated lens cap slip pocket, so your lens cap is never misplaced
Feature=Holds Cameras up to 5.9 x 4 x 6 x 7.5"
ItemDimensions=46059024750
Label=Case Logic
ListPrice=2999USD$29.99
Manufacturer=Case Logic
Model=SHC-101-BK
MPN=SHC-101-BK
PackageDimensions=27694526787
PackageQuantity=4
PartNumber=SHC-101-BK
ProductGroup=Photography
ProductTypeName=CAMERA_BAGS_AND_CASES
Publisher=Case Logic
SKU=12360967Pixmania14388
Studio=Case Logic
Title=Case Logic SHC-101-BK DSLR Day Holster, Small, Black
UPC=085854223799
UPCList=085854223799
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider the GS1 [Global Product Classification (GPC)](https://www.gs1.org/standards/gpc).

> GPC classifies products by grouping them into categories based on their essential properties as well as their relationships to other products. GPC offers a universal set of standards for everything from a car to a litre of milk.

The GS1 standards are the basis for global supply chains.

GPC Hierarchy:

[image: GPC Example Hierarchy]

Brick attributes / values.

[image: Example of brick attributes / values]

After that there are taxonomies / dictionaries for attribute values.